# Quick smoke effect disappear after succesfully baking

Tags: smoke-simulation, mantaflow

I’m using Blender 3.1. I have a smoke domain (quick smoke effect). It plays well in *Replay* mode. In *All* mode, Baking completes successfully and the files are generated in the folder. However, the smoke won’t show up anymore.

I tried *Modular* and *All*.
I’m using EEVEE, but same problem happens with Cycles.

I’ve seen several youtube videos in which previous Blender versions had the same issue. Non of the solutions worked for me like deleting the bake directory, switching EEVEE to Cycles and go back to EEVEE, switching modular mode, switching compression modules.

Any clues would be welcome.